# PHP - undefined array

Tags: php, arrays, undefined

the class below is part of an mvc structure im building for my website. the class is there to produce a page if index.php is called without any request in the url. if that is good practice or not I do not know. Im new to php, and this is the first time i implement an mvc structure.

```
<?php

class Default_Model
{
    private $defaultPage = array
    (
        'headline' => 'JOBBSÖKAREN', 
        'instruction' => 'logga in nedanför'    
    );

    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    public function getContent()
    {
line 17     return $defaultPage;
    }
}
?>
```

here is the error message: 
Notice: Undefined variable: defaultPage in /home/mengus/dev/www/models/default.php on line 17

so what I dont get is why the array is undefined. I use similar code in other classes and it works just fine. is it a scope issue? I seem to have gone error blind from staring at this :)
thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

To access the fields you need to use `$this` and `->` operator

```
return $this->defaultPage;
```

Comment: @Sujit Singh: I'm sorry, your change is terribly wrong (from terminology point of view), rolled back

Comment: @zerkms : i guess, i was right. See, in a function if we want to refer any variable, (say, for example $in) which is declared inside that function, we will access directly like $in, but if that variable is declared outside function, but, naturally, inside controller, we have to use $this->variable_name to access it. Am I right ?

Comment: @Sujit Singh: there is no "inside" function and "outside" function. There are fields and methods. Please use the correct terminology. You're right technically, but the terms you've just  invented are terrible.

Comment: @zerkms : so you mean, instead of terms "variable" and "function", i should have used "fields" and "methods" ?

Comment: @Sujit Singh: http://php.net/oop - they are the basic terms of php's (and any other imperative programming language) Object Model. So, yes, the "class' function" is a method, the instance variable - is a field (or property). Though in some programming languages property and field mean different things.

Comment: very interesting. But how come a method cannot directly access fields of the same instance?

Comment: @Mengus: I didn't get you. You're specifying the `$this` reference explicitly. `$this` - is a reference to a current object.

Comment: yes, thats kind of my point. I come from a c++ world and there the this reference, in situations like this is basicly for show. the compiler knows that if I dont specify anything else then the current object is what I want. I wonder why php need me to clarify this.

Comment: @Mengus: oh, from that point. Yes, in comparison to c++, java and c# - php requires this object reference explicitly.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up for me. when I've been looking through php code, I've wondered how come there's this references everywhere. still don't make sense to me, but if its what the compiler wants, its what it gets. maybe it has something to do with php not being specificly designed for oop?